# Sorting entire matrix according to one column in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

I have the matrix as follows

```
a =

 1     3
 2     5
 3     2
 4     8
 5     9
```

I want to sort the second column in the `a` matrix. I want the corresponding rows of column one to be printed as follows :

```
a =

 3     2
 1     3
 2     5
 4     8
 5     9
```

I tried `sort(a)`, but it is sorting only the second column of matrix `a`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

`sortrows(a,2)`

This should sort according to the second column.

Answer (score 7):

or use:

```
[val idx]=sort(a(:,2));
ans = [a(idx,1) val]
```